# CS50 Mario Python - more

Tags: python-3.x, cs50

Trying Python for the Mario more assignment in CS50 - print out a double half-pyramid of a specified height. The code and output looks correct to me, but check50 results are bad.
Please tell me, is there something I'm doing wrong?
https://submit.cs50.io/check50/05296ef97446aba062bd8e9993587e347da25878

```
from cs50 import get_int
while True:
    n = get_int("Height: \n")
    if n > 0 and n < 9:
        break
for i in range(n):
print(" " * (n-1-i), end="")
print("#" * (i+1), end="  ")
print("#" * (i+1), end="")
print(" " * (n-1-i))
```

Comment: Your indentations are wrong and the last print statement is unnecessary, you can also just put all of your code into 1 print statement if you want to

Comment: in the errors it says......`Did you add too much trailing whitespace to the end of your pyramid?` your adding trailing space at the end, is that trailing space meant to be there?

Comment: Thanks! Got caught up in the symmetry, realized now I don't need that and it worked:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check50 does not want spaces after the second row of # blocks.  To us humans the lack of characters and space characters look the same, but check50 can tell the difference.  In other words, delete the last print line.

Also, perhaps you copy and pasted into here wrong, but white space matters in python whereas it didn't in C.  This means that you must indent the lines that you ant included in the if block.